# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: importlib install failed (ImportError: No module named '_frozen_importlib_external')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, fatal-error, cx-freeze

I am trying to make my python code containing tkinter an executable file using **cx_Freeze** in python3.5, When i try to execute my exe file, it crashes saying...
`ImportError: No module named '_frozen_importlib_external'`

[image]

My code takes an input as csv file from user,loads the same into pandas dataframe and applies regression on the data. Now i used cx_freeze as

```
import sys
import cx_Freeze
base = None

if sys.platform == 'Win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("6_demo.py", base = base,targetName="anac.exe")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "model",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","pandas"]}},
    description = "Predicts the outcome",
    executables = executables,

)
```

Comment: can you add more details about it?

Comment: @Miki  have added the setup.py i used for cx_Freeze

Comment: hey SURESH2692 did you got any solution for this question, because me too getting the same error and cant find any solution pls suggest me if there is a solution.

Comment: @Dinesh Nope, I think cx_Freeze doesn't support python3. I used pyinstaller for python2.7 and made it work.